# Automatically scroll down based on selection

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, scrollview, autoscroll

[image]

I am using a Rating controller in my application.
Whenever the user selects a rating on the selection view, data is changed.

But when the user selects stars I need to scroll automatically.

I wrote the following code but it gave extra scrolling space than the view height on scrollview. like shown in image

```
if (self.scrollview.contentOffset.y != ratingMainview.frame.minY) {
    self.scrollview.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y:ratingMainview.frame.minY), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of your issue?

Comment: Add more details of the issue

Comment: The image you added doesn't clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, but two details are missing. 
First, contentOffset is inverted, so you need a minus sign: -ratingMainview.frame.minY.
Second, I'm not sure you mean to use ratingMainview.frame.minY. minY is the top of the view.